# How to find average of tuples in relational algebra calculator

Tags: relational-algebra

Problem is to use the  `group by` function to find only the average of books checked out by students of a specific department. However, it keeps outputting the average of all checked out books from all students.

What I have so far:

```
γ avg(Books_Quantity) -> y (Student) ⨝ (σ Department = 'Computer_Science' (Student))
```

The output should be 1.75, but is instead outputting the average for all the departments.

```
y   Student.Student_ID  Student.Student_Name    Student.Department  Student.Books_Quantity

1.5 1                   John                    Computer_Science    2

1.5 2                   Lisa                    Computer_Science    1

1.5 5                   Xina                    Computer_Science    3

1.5 7                   Chang                   Computer_Science    1
```

Comment: There are many RAs (relational algebras). They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Give a reference and/or definition for yours. Eg textbook name, edition & page. RA is for programming. Please in code questions give a mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as tabular initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. You have to put the Select option inside the table selection operation. Like so:

```
γ avg(Books_Quantity) -> y (σ Department = 'Computer_Science' (Student))
```